# How to build C++ code using scons for solaris compatible OS using jenkins?

Tags: c++, jenkins, solaris, scons

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout<<"Starting Program"<<std::endl;
   int a = 10;
   int b = 20;
   int c = a + b;
   std::cout<<"Sum of A and B is "<<c<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"Ending Program"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my SConstruct script file:

```
env = Environment(platform='sunos')
env.Program('hello.C')
```

Does above SConstruct file is correct to build hello.C for solaris ? Will this work. Any suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Presumably you will need to install your own scons + any dependencies that either don't come with base Solaris or are too old.

Comment: Yes we are going to try it using jenkins bu installing scons plugin. Hence got doubt about the platform specific variables to use in sconstruct script file.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

1. Setup a Solaris machine x86/SPARC
2. Install SCons, GCC, other dependencies
3. Set it up as a Jenkins node

I believe SCons will select the GCC toolchain on any non-windows host, so no need for `platform='sunos'` environment.

Comment: yes we have sparc machine. (SunOS dvc7959 5.10 Generic_150400-20 sun4v sparc sun4v) and we are trying to install scons plugins in jenkins and trying to build our code that supports for solaris/sparc.

Comment: @satheesh  Looking at the scons plugin I see almost no benefit compared to invoking scons from a Jenkinsfile sh step (or whatever solaris uses for command line). In addition the latest release was 9y ago and marked as "up for adoption". Red flags all over.

Comment: Jenkins will be hosted on Linux machine.And will access jenkins on windows machine and by through that scons plugin is used to build code that supports for solaris. Where the code will be placed in clearcase/git.

Comment: @satheesh That's fine, not suggesting anything contradicting the overall setup. What you'd do is setup the sparc machine as a a **build node** where Jenkins 
 (master) can send build jobs. This assumes you can setup a native build environment on the sparc machine: https://yallalabs.com/devops/how-to-add-linux-slave-node-agent-node-jenkins/ (link is setup by SSH, there is also a Java based setup)

Comment: I manage the SCons project and didn't even know there was a Jenkins plugin for it. It's not "official". I'd just call scons on the command line and skip the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify platform

```
env = Environment()
env.Program('hello.C')
```

Should suffice.

It doesn't matter what platform your jenkins is running on, as long as your build worker is on Solaris, SCons will detect that and try to build.

Comment: I have added platform to build the binary to be compatible for solaris OS.

Comment: @satheesh - SCons should detect what platform you are on and compile for that platform. You should not need to explicitly set platform.

Comment: following are the setup we have. 1.Jenkins installed on Linux machine.2.c++ code in repository.ex clearcase/git.3.scons plugins installed on Jenkins.4.Now I need to build c++ code using scons plugins of Jenkins hosted on Linux machine where c++ binary to built is to be compatible for Solaris os. Hence added platform variable. If not added, does the buit binary runs on Solaris os. Is is possible to build like this.

Comment: @satheesh - so you want to build binaries for a solaris machine while compiling on a linux machine? setting platform to solaris won't do that. You need to compile the binary on a solaris machine. If you do that, SCons will properly detect the platform and compile appropriately.

Comment: yes correct , I need to build like that. Is there is any other build tool (like scons, Nmake etc) to build in such a way that build in jenkins(ie. on linux) for solaris compatible machine.

Comment: @satheesh - Jenkins is a CI tool, not a build tool. SCons can build on windows, linux, macos, freebsd, solaris, and others.  You really would benefit from reading the SCons users guide and perhaps joining the community on IRC, users mailing list, and/or our discord server.